# is there a way to automatically order tmux panes in the order they where created?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tmux

I made a script to run mutiple peers of a chord-ring in a tmux session.

```
tmux new -s peers -d

# Do this multiple times
tmux send-keys <ProgramName> C-m
tmux select-pane -t :.+
tmux split-window -v -t peers

tmux select-layout tiled
tmux attach -t peers
```

I would like the panes to be ordered like this:

```
 _ _ _ 
|0|1|2|
 _ _ _ 
|3|4|5|
 _ _ _ 
|6|7|8|
```

The numbers represent the order in which the panes where created.

Is it possible to sort the panes in this order automatically?

Comment: what order did you get? not sorted by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do select-pane before split, you effectively re-order.

If you keep splitting the newest pane, you won't have this problem. You just need to make sure it's big enough.

```
tmux new -s peers -d

(( i=0, n=8, h=2*n ))
while
    tmux send-keys "echo ${i}" C-m
    (( i++ < n ))
do
    tmux split-window -v -t peers -l${h}
done

tmux select-layout tiled
tmux attach -t peers
```

---

It appears the above code is buggy.

This more thorough version (implemented as bash function but could just be a script) seems to work more reliably:

```
tmux-new-nxn-session(){
    wname=$1
    n=$2

    tmux new -s "$wname" -d

    (( i=1, nxn=(n*n), h=2*nxn ))
    tmux resize-window -t "$wname" -y $h
    while
        tmux send-keys "echo ${i}" C-m
        (( i++ < nxn ))
    do
        tmux split-window -v -t "$wname" -l${h}
    done

    tmux select-layout -t "$wname" tiled
    tmux set-option -t "$wname" window-size latest
    tmux attach -t "$wname"
}
```

For example, for 6x6, call as: `tmux-new-nxn-session "peers" 6`

- `resize-window` sets window size explicitly to ensure it is big enough
- `set-option` removes the "manual" `window-size` status so that it will resize to fit the viewing terminal
- there is no error-checking to ensure `wname` doesn't already exist

Comment: thank you, that seems to work. But if I try to create a 4*4 layout I get `no space for new pane` error. is there a way to get around that? with my old script i was able to run 16 sessions at once and then this message came. But for my purpose it could fit event more terminals on my screen...

Comment: Did you increase `n`?  It is the number of splits being done. Increase it to 15 if you want 16 panes. `h` is the number of lines for split-window's `-l` option and needs to be at least 2*`n` to avoid the `no space` error.

Comment: @TheBaum Looks like there may have been an off-by-one error in my height computation. Also, may need to set window size to ensure it is big enough. See new code